# What could be an alternative word implying 'to endorse someone'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, slang

On professional [social network sites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_networking_service) (like [LinkedIn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn)) there are terms like 'recommend someone' or 'endorse someone'. What could be an alternative term that is somewhat lighter in meaning as compared to endorsing someone, but rather more inclined towards meaning 'to appreciate someone in academic or professional context or to appreciate his works'?

I need to use a noun as well as a verb of the term.

Comment: What are 'SN sites'?

Comment: @Jez, Social Network (e.g. linkedin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few possibilities:

- to support/to back.
- to value

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

> Approve/Approof/Approval
>   Advance/advancement

Comment: No, a typo. :-)

Comment: I saw it [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/approof)

Answer (score 1):

How about **associate**:

> *noun*
>   a partner or colleague in business or at work
>
> *verb*
>   ( associate oneself with) allow oneself to be connected with or seen to be supportive of

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the context you are going for, so maybe too lighthearted, but if you're leaning away from the "endorse" or "vouch for" idea, maybe you just want something that casually indicates that we could/did hang out together such as, "High Fives" or "Lunches with."

Answer (score 0):

I believe "thumbs up" or "like" covers this.